# Mysql select 1 row inside a function

Tags: mysql, sql, function, variables, resultset

i have a table with about 100 columns,and a stored function that selects one (exactly one) row and does some work with 30 of its fields. Right now i declare 30 variables,fetch row data into them, then process them. I was wondering if i could just fetch the row and use it instead, but searching on google for a while and testing yielded no results.

E.g.:

what i do now is

```
declare var1,var2,var3 etc.. smallint default 0;
select field1,field2,field3,etc into var1,var2,var3,etc from table where id=1;
then i use var1,2,3 etc
```

with 30 variables,the code is unreadable.

what i want to do is something like

```
select * from table as r where id=1;
 and then use r.field1,r.field2,r.field3
```

Can this be done?
Thanks for your time

Comment: why no using a temp table inside a procedure? select the data/row create temp table, insert the data in it, cursor that data and apply you logic on it !

Comment: the whole procedure just uses data from one row in the table, and i need to use 30 fields in that row. I don't see how a temp table could help me, can you explain please?